# In a Transformer, how to specify that the types fo the classes being transformed are of the same type?

Tags: java, generics

I'm having a very simple yet confuse question at the same time.

In a Transformer, is there a way to specify that the types of the classes being transformed are the same type?

To make it clear, I'll share the code:

```
Transformer<Set<?>, List<?>> transformer = new SetToListTransformer();
```

Is there a way for me to specify that the Set and the List are of the same type?

Also when writing the transformer I did this, and I assume it serves no purpose:

```
private static class SetToListTransformer implements Transformer<Set<?>, List<?>> {

  @Override
  public List<?> transform(final Set<?> input) {
     return this.doTransform(input);
  }

  public <T> List<T> doTransform(final Set<T> input) {
      ...
  }
}
```

The thing is, I cannot type the SetToListTransformer since I do not really care about what types are inside, I just care that they are the same type.

Any help would be appreciated!

PS: I'm not really transforming a Set into a List, I'm using other types, I just used them to clarify the code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to enforce the desired constraint on your `transform` implementation, since there is no way to impose any relationship between generic wildcards. Each of the two `?` in your `SetToListTransformer` declaration are doomed to each mean *some unknown type* with no way to bound them to each other.

As others pointed out, the easiest solution is to make `SetToListTransformer` generic. For example:

```
class SetToListTransformer<T> implements Transformer<Set<? extends T>, List<T>> {

    @Override
    public List<T> transform(final Set<? extends T> input) {
        final List<T> output = new ArrayList<T>(input.size());
        output.addAll(input);
        return output;
    }
}
```

Of course this requires you to instantiate transformers with specific type arguments. This should be fine as long as `SetToListTransformer` is cheap. But, you indicated you just want to use one instance. Here's how to do that:

```
class MyTransformers {

    // There is no reason to expose SetToListTransformer now.
    // Keep it here as an anonymous class.
    private static final Transformer<Set<?>, List<?>> FROM_SET_TO_LIST =
            new Transformer<Set<?>, List<?>>() {
                @Override
                public List<?> transform(final Set<?> input) {
                    return doTransform(input);
                }
                private <T> List<T> doTransform(final Set<T> input) {
                    final List<T> output = new ArrayList<T>(input.size());
                    output.addAll(input);
                    return output;
                }
            };

    private MyTransformers() { }

    public static <T> Transformer<Set<? extends T>, List<T>> fromSetToList() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")//this is okay for any T because the impl is stateless 
        final Transformer<Set<? extends T>, List<T>> withNarrowedTypes =
                (Transformer<Set<? extends T>, List<T>>)(Transformer<?, ?>)FROM_SET_TO_LIST;
        return withNarrowedTypes;
    }
}
```

Here's a usage example:

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
intSet.add(42);
intSet.add(1337);
List<Number> numList = MyTransformers.<Number>fromSetToList().transform(intSet);
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to cast the transformed class:

"List<Integer> aList = transformer.transform(aSet);" doesn't compile

Comment: **Thanks a lot!** So basically there's no way to have that in an instance, but I could have a method that returns an instance that provides that functionality (though I can never assign that instance to something like `Transformer(Set<T>, List<T>>` without specifying an actual T.

Comment: @matafuego That's right. It's a minor optimization/stylistic change that requires using a cast that would typically be unsafe (hence the suppressed warnings). In this *particular* case, we the know it's fine to use the same instance because what it actually does is the same for any `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to bind both wildcards to the same type paramter, like this:

```
class SetToListTransformer<E> implements Transformer<Set<E>, List<E>> { 
    @Override
    public List<E> transform(Set<E> from) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I have with that is that I can't really instantiate it later. I can't do: Transformer<Set<?>, List<?>> transformer = new SetToListTransformer();

Answer (score 1):

Make your class generic:

```
private static class SetToListTransformer <T> implements Transformer<Set<T>, List<T>> {

  @Override
  public List<T> transform(Set<T> input) {
     return this.doTransform(input);
  }

  public List<T> doTransform(Set<T> input) {
      ...
  }
}
```

Note, however, that this implementation is quite strict with types. You wont be able to use a SetToListTransformer<Number> to convert from Set<Integer> to List<Number>, although Integer IS a Number.

Comment: I had that, but how do I instantiate it?
I can´t do:

Transformer<Set<?>, List<?>> transformer = new SetToListTransformer<?>();


And the transformer doesn't really care about the types.

Comment: @matafuego: Why not using the specific type arguments when you construct the transformer?

Comment: @matafuego: Transformer<Set<Integer>,List<Integer>> tr = new SetToListTransformer<Integer>();

Comment: Because I don't know the specific type. I could have a Set of Integers or a Set of Strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can't express that constraint with the `Transformer` interface. You may create a subtype that imposes additional constraints, and use the subtype where `Transformer` was used.

```
interface StricterTransformer extends Transformer<Set<?>, List<?>>

    public <T> List<T> transform2(Set<T> input) ;

    /** javadoc additional contract: must behave as transform2(input) */
    public List<?> transform(Set<?> input);
    // in java8 we can give a "default" impl for this interface method
    // that simply calls transform2(), so subclasses don't have to impl 
    // the transform() method, which is just boiler plate code.
```